# Install the Azure Modules

Tags: azure, python-module

I am new to Azure. How to install the below Azure Modules on the windows server via command prompt? Should I download anything before installing?

The modules are:

1. azure.common.credentials
2. azure.keyvault.secrets
3. azure.identity

Answer (score 1):

Using the Install-Module cmdlet is the preferred installation method for the Az PowerShell module. Install the Az module for the current user only. This is the recommended installation scope. This method works the same on Windows, macOS, and Linux platforms. Run the following command from a PowerShell session. Run PowerShell in Administrator:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

Or Offline Instalation Method go to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps-msi?view=azps-6.4.0